# DotNet5 Console app gives error on Linux but DotNetCore 3.1 app runs fine

Tags: .net-core, yocto, .net-5

I want to run a DotNet5 Console app on Yocto Linux (Dunfell). We run this on a iMX8MM based CPU module. I have followed the manufacturers guide to clone the repos and have a custom Yocto Build running.
The Issue I'm now having is that a Hello World c# app compiled as a self-contained DotNet5 app gives this error:

```
./VarisciteTest: error while loading shared libraries: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I compile the same app as DotNetCore 3.1 it runs just fine.

I tried adding `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "krb5"` to the local.conf (as a quick test) but that does not help.

Can someone tell me what dependency I need to add to Yocto to make Dotnet5 apps run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you need to add this:

```
libgssapi-krb5
```

to the recipe of the Yocto build.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you add it to DEPENDS or RDEPENDS?

Comment: @BillCraun We created a custom Layer and we added it to the layer.conf file:
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "libgssapi-krb5"